# trouble with friendly_id gem, issues when trying to target the correct id

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

So I am building a website for school that consists of different wikis that users can create, update, edit, etc.  On my wiki edit page I allow an option for premium users to add or remove collaborators to a wiki that they have created if they choose to check their wiki as private.

I designed this add/remove collaborators feature to be used with AJAX so that a user can toggle back and forth with another user that they choose to add or remove as a collaborator without refreshing the page.

Before I implemented the friendly_id gem, my add/remove feature was working just fine.  However, after implementing the friendly_id gem, I've noticed a new bug that had been created.  Let me explain..

Whenever I click to add a user as a collaborator, things appear as if they have worked and I am able to toggle back and forth from adding and removing.  However, the user that I am trying to add initially is not getting added as a collaborator, and it is apparent in the stack trace.

This is what happens after clicking the 'add' link for the first time:

```
Started POST "/wikis/hipsters/collaborators?user_id=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-28 17:51:06 -0700
Processing by CollaboratorsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"3", "wiki_id"=>"hipsters"}
  Wiki Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "wikis".* FROM "wikis"  WHERE "wikis"."slug" = 'hipsters'  ORDER BY "wikis"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "collaborators" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id", "wiki_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-09-29 00:51:06.185794"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-29 00:51:06.185794"], ["user_id", 3], ["wiki_id", 0]]
   (85.8ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "collaborators"  WHERE "collaborators"."wiki_id" = ?  [["wiki_id", 51]]
  Rendered collaborators/create.js.haml (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 198ms (Views: 106.9ms | ActiveRecord: 86.8ms)
```

Notice how a new collaborator is attempted to be made with a `["user_id", 3], ["wiki_id", 0]`

The user_id is correct, but the wiki_id is not.  Why is this happening?  The friendly_id gem is working, as you can see the name of this particular wiki is "hipsters".

This is made apparent here:

```
Parameters: {"user_id"=>"3", "wiki_id"=>"hipsters"}
  Wiki Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "wikis".* FROM "wikis"  WHERE "wikis"."slug" = 'hipsters'  ORDER BY "wikis"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

However, since I just attempted to 'add' a user as a collaborator, now the link has toggled to read 'remove', to get rid of a collaborator.

Upon clicking to remove the collaborator, my server log displays the following:

```
Started DELETE "/wikis/51/collaborators/54" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-28 18:02:39 -0700
Processing by CollaboratorsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"wiki_id"=>"51", "id"=>"54"}
  Wiki Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "wikis".* FROM "wikis"  WHERE "wikis"."slug" = '51'  ORDER BY "wikis"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Wiki Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "wikis".* FROM "wikis"  WHERE "wikis"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 51]]
  Collaborator Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "collaborators".* FROM "collaborators"  WHERE "collaborators"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 54]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "collaborators" WHERE "collaborators"."id" = ?  [["id", 54]]
   (30.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "collaborators"  WHERE "collaborators"."wiki_id" = ?  [["wiki_id", 51]]
  Rendered collaborators/destroy.js.haml (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 16.1ms | ActiveRecord: 31.3ms)
```

Then, when I toggle to add the user as a collaborator again, this time they actually get added.

Server log:

```
Started POST "/wikis/51/collaborators?user_id=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-28 18:05:59 -0700
Processing by CollaboratorsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"3", "wiki_id"=>"51"}
  Wiki Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "wikis".* FROM "wikis"  WHERE "wikis"."slug" = '51'  ORDER BY "wikis"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Wiki Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "wikis".* FROM "wikis"  WHERE "wikis"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 51]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "collaborators" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id", "wiki_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-09-29 01:05:59.564379"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-29 01:05:59.564379"], ["user_id", 3], ["wiki_id", 51]]
   (182.8ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "collaborators"  WHERE "collaborators"."wiki_id" = ?  [["wiki_id", 51]]
  Rendered collaborators/create.js.haml (3.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 198ms (Views: 8.3ms | ActiveRecord: 184.2ms)
```

I notice that this time around the parameters read `Parameters: {"user_id"=>"3", "wiki_id"=>"51"}` instead of `Parameters: {"user_id"=>"3", "wiki_id"=>"hipsters"}`

Why is this?  How can I get this feature to function correctly?

Here's some relevant files:

wikis_controller.rb:

```
class WikisController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @wikis = policy_scope(Wiki)
  end

  def show
    @wiki = Wiki.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @wiki = Wiki.new

    authorize @wiki # Example
  end

  def create
    @wiki = Wiki.new(wiki_params)

    @wiki.user = current_user

    authorize @wiki

    if @wiki.save
      flash[:notice] = "Wiki was saved."
      redirect_to @wiki
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the wiki.  Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @wiki = Wiki.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @users = User.all

    authorize Wiki, :edit?
  end

  def update
    @wiki = Wiki.friendly.find(params[:id])

    authorize @wiki

    if @wiki.update_attributes(wiki_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Wiki was updated."
      redirect_to @wiki
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the wiki.  Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @wiki = Wiki.friendly.find(params[:id])

    authorize Wiki, :destroy?

    if @wiki.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@wiki.title}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to wikis_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the wiki."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private

  def wiki_params
    params.require(:wiki).permit(:title, :body, :private)
  end
end
```

collaborators_controller.rb:

```
class CollaboratorsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @wiki = Wiki.friendly.find(params[:wiki_id])
    @collaborator = Collaborator.create(wiki_id: params[:wiki_id], user_id: params[:user_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @wiki = Wiki.friendly.find(params[:wiki_id])
    @collab = Collaborator.find(params[:id])
    @user_id = @collab.user_id
    @collab.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

collaborators/create.js.haml:

```
- if @collaborator.save
  $('#'+#{ params[:user_id] }).replaceWith('<a data-method="delete" data-remote="true" href="/wikis/'+#{ @wiki.id }+'/collaborators/'+#{ @collaborator.id }+'" id="#{ @collaborator.user_id }" rel="nofollow">Remove</a>');
  $('.js-collaborators-count').html("Currently #{ pluralize(@wiki.collaborators.count, 'collaborator') } on this wiki.");
- else
  $('#'+#{ params[:user_id] }).prepend("<div class='alert alert-danger'>#{ flash[:error] = 'Oops something went wrong..' }</div>");
```

collaborators/destroy.js.haml:

```
- if @collab.destroyed?
  $('#'+#{ @user_id.to_s }).replaceWith('<a data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="/wikis/'+#{ @wiki.id }+'/collaborators?user_id=#{ @user_id }" id="#{ @user_id }" rel="nofollow">Add</a>');
  $('.js-collaborators-count').html("Currently #{ pluralize(@wiki.collaborators.count, 'collaborator') } on this wiki.");
- else
  $('#'+#{ @user_id.to_s }).prepend("<div class='alert alert-danger'>#{ flash[:error] = 'Oops something went wrong..' }</div>");
```

wikis/edit.html.haml:

```
%h1 Edit Wiki

.row
  .col-md-8
    = form_for @wiki do |f|
      .form-group
        = f.label :title
        = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter wiki title"
      .form-group
        = f.label :body
        = f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter wiki body"

      - if current_user.role == 'admin' || (current_user.role == 'premium' && @wiki.user == current_user)
        = render 'wikis/form', f: f

      - if current_user.role == 'admin' || (@wiki.private == true && @wiki.user == current_user)
        .form-group
          %h5
            Add/Remove Collaborators to the
            %em &ldquo;#{ @wiki.title }&rdquo;
            wiki (Showing all users)
          %small
            .js-collaborators-count
              Currently #{ pluralize(@wiki.collaborators.count, 'collaborator') } on this wiki.
          .col-sm-4.text-center.outline
            %h6.underline Name
            - @users.each do |u|
              .border_bottom
                = u.name
                %br/

          .col-sm-4.text-center.outline
            %h6.underline Email
            - @users.each do |u|
              .border_bottom
                = u.email

          .col-sm-4.text-center.outline
            %h6.underline Give Access
            - @users.each do |u|
              .border_bottom
                - if collab = u.collaborators.find_by(wiki_id: @wiki.id)
                  = link_to "Remove", wiki_collaborator_path(@wiki, collab), method: :delete, remote: true, id: u.id
                - else
                  = link_to "Add", wiki_collaborators_path(@wiki, user_id: u.id), method: :post, remote: true, id: u.id

      .form-group
        = f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-success mt_10'
```

If I left any files out you can view my repo on github here:

https://github.com/jlquaccia/blocipedia

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong.  Inside of the collaborators_controller within the create action I had to change

```
@collaborator = Collaborator.create(wiki_id: params[:wiki_id], user_id: params[:user_id])
```

to

```
@collaborator = Collaborator.create(wiki_id: @wiki.id, user_id: params[:user_id])
```

The `params[:wiki_id]` was targeting the friendly_id slug when it should have been targeting the `@wiki.id`